# Query returns nothing from database

Tags: java, postgresql

I'm trying to get a car from my database using the value `FK_adId`. I've tried calling the method with the `FK_adId` value 52, and I've checked that a car with the `FK_adId` value 52 exists in my database. Why doesn't it get returned to me?

```
public Car getCar(int adId) {
    Car car = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        if (con != null) {
            ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM \"car\" WHERE \"FK_adId\" = ?;");
            ps.setInt(1, adId);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            rs.next();
            if (rs.next()) {
                car = new Car(rs.getString("brand"), rs.getString("vin"), rs.getString("condition"), rs.getInt("distanceTraveled"), rs.getInt("age"), rs.getInt("price"), rs.getInt("FK_adId"));
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
    return car;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
>         rs.next();
>    if (rs.next()) {
> ```

Call `.next()` once, not twice.  You advance to the first row of the results, then you advance to the second. Since the query did not return two rows, you do not get the second row.  You skipped the row you wanted.